# backbone console log event triggering

Tags: events, backbone.js, triggers, console

I've got a underscore/backbone/require application and I would like to output all events that are triggered through backbone to the console (in other words: pass each event through `console.log` function). I've tried wrapping it with underscore and manually replacing the function. Neither this:

```
console.log(Backbone.Events.trigger);
var trigger = Backbone.Events.trigger;
Backbone.Events.trigger = function(name) {
    console.log('Event', name, 'triggered.');
    trigger.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

nor this:

```
Backbone.Events.trigger = _.wrap(Backbone.Events.trigger, function(func) {
    console.log('EVENT:', Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    func(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
});
console.log(Backbone.Events.trigger);
```

worked. I'd appreciate a javascript (not coffeescript) solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your wrappings fail because Backbone mixes in `Backbone.Events` behavior on `Backbone.Model`, `Backbone.Collection`, etc. For example, `Backbone.Model` is defined as

```
var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    ...
};
_.extend(Model.prototype, Events, {
    ...
};
```

This means that when you redefine `Backbone.Events.trigger`, it is already too late.

But all is not lost! You won't be able to redefine all `trigger` methods in one go, but you can redefine them on class level:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.trigger = function() {
    console.log('Event', arguments);
    Backbone.Events.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

and a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/G2Qfn/

For a given class, you can override the trigger method:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    trigger: function() {
        console.log('Event', arguments);
        Backbone.Model.prototype.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/G2Qfn/1/

or for a given instance

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var m = new M();   
m.trigger = function() {
    console.log('Event', arguments);
    M.prototype.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/G2Qfn/2/

Comment: This is just what I need, thank you! I can see that if I fetch a model from an API, all fields from all models send events. Is there any way to attach such thing into a chosen backbone model?

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz I added some examples to restrict the behavior to a class or an instance.